# Unexpected Request Error with $HttpBackend (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, httpbackend, angularjs-ngmock

I am using HttpBackend to mock some Http responses for some calls that my Angular app is making.

However, I am getting the error **"Unexpected Request: [object Object] undefined"** when I run my tests.

I know that usually this error means you're missing or mistyped one of the $http requests that the app makes so it can't find a response. But my error is not specific like the other ones which usually say like **"Unexpected Request: GET api/call"** so I don't know what is wrong.

Has anyone ever encountered this specific error before?

Sample Code

angular controller:

```
app.controller( 'ctrl', 
   [ '$scope' , '$http' , '$location', function( $scope, $http, $location ) {
        $http.get(
            "/api/1.0/id/" + id, 
            {
                headers: getAuthHeaders()
            }
        ).success(function( data ){ //... })]
);
```

jasmine test:

```
it('should ...', function(){
  httpBackend.whenGET('/api/1.0/id/*').respond(200,{"test":"Test"});
  //...
});
```

Comment: `getAuthHeaders()` what is this function returning? I think that your headers are not what you think it is :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the headers are correct because my api calls are actually working. Also, it shouldn't matter what the header is for the mock right?

Comment: So it's only the http mock that's failing? -- Maybe, if the headers are wacky (for instance, [object Ojbect] instead of an acual Object) it might screw it all to nothingness

Comment: Yes only mock is failing. My actual api calls all work.

Comment: That's mighty weird, "Unexpected Request" normaly throws when the request that you made was a mal-formed request. I'm at loss here..

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and test by myself. I add a function to set the ID, but I think you have something simular:

```
 //PRESET ID
 var id = 'deajedgwe1e213df';

        //FUNCTION TO CAPSULATE API CALL
        this.callApi = function () {
            http.get(
                "/api/1.0/id/" + id,
                {
                    //headers: getAuthHeaders()
                }
            ).success(function( data ){
                    console.log('success', data);
                }).error(function (err) {
                    console.log('error', err);
                });
        };

        //FUNCTION TO SET ID
        this.setId = function (ID) {
              id = ID;
        };
```

then I copied your test and modified it like this:

```
  it('should ...', function(){
      ctrl.setId('test123ID');

      httpBackend.expectGET('/api/1.0/id/test123ID').respond(200,{"test":"Test"});

      ctrl.callApi();

      httpBackend.flush();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
```

this works. alternative you could do this:

```
   it('should ...', function(){

      httpBackend.expectGET(/api/i).respond(200,{"test":"Test"});

      ctrl.callApi();

      httpBackend.flush();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
```

this works too, but it only verifies, that /api has been called... I don't if this is that, what you want to test.

I think the major problem is your asterisk notation at the api-call. try to modify your code like mine. if this shouldn't help, you should have a call on your header function.

Good luck.